# how to take a print of server side response file on click of button?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a webpage with react and material ui. on webpage I have defined print icon. I have to print file on click of print icon. File is fetched from backend as a  response.  I dont know how to print a file?
below is function code on print icon click

```
const printFiles = (email:any,data:any) => {
    var request = new Request('http://localhost:3030/node/express/companyfiles/download/' + email + '/', {
        method:'GET',
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/zip',}),
       })
fetch(request)
 .then(response => ( response.json() ))
    
 .then(data)
   console.log(data)
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have any methods of interacting with output devices, which means you cannot use plain JS to print. You can however use a library like `Print.js` at [Printjs](https://printjs.crabbly.com/).

Install it like so

`npm install print-js --save`

Import it to your component like so

`import printJS from 'print-js'`

then pass it the file/data you need printed

`printJS('docs/PrintJS.pdf')`

In your case

```
    var request = new Request('http://localhost:3030/node/express/companyfiles/download/' + email + '/', {
        method:'GET',
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/zip',}),
       })
fetch(request)
 .then(response => ( response.json() ))
    
 .then(data)
   printJS(data)
 }
```